# Windows Server 2008R2 and 2012R2 VM installs

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2

I have not done server admin on windows before and I have some questions about where I can find guides or information to help me with my questions:

1. Can you setup an install of these VM's with scripts that add local accounts?
2. Can you script/automate the install of MSSQL 2008R2?
3. Can you script/automate installation of 3rd party software?

I guess really what I am after is a way to automate the server stand-up for a specific application in a automated way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can definitely install windows server VMs using the script. See windows packer script how to create an image for your virtualisation environment (virtual box, vmware etc).

You can use vagrant to create as many instance from the image as you want and provision the MSSQL and other server by scripts. To provision the scripts you can use powerhshell's DSC or search ansible role.

See a very good guide provided at https://dennypc.wordpress.com/2014/12/02/vagrant-provisioning-powershell-dsc/

check the vagrant website from hashicorp and MSDN for the powershell DSC.